# Average group size from survey

Tags: sampling, survey

I'm working on this puzzle: The people in a country are partitioned into clans. In order to estimate the average size of a clan, a survey is conducted where randomly selected people are asked to state the size of the clan to which they belong. How does one compute an estimate average clan size from the data collected? If you take a pure average of the surveyed people you will overestimate the group size because you will have more representatives from the larger clans. Thus each sampled variable needs to be downweighted in some way -- to factor out multiple samples from the same clan. Any ideas?